# How can I use limits in everyday life?

Tags: calculus

Today I completed the chapter of '**Limits **' in my school, and I found this chapter very fascinating. But the only problem I have with limits and Derivatives is that I don't know How can I use it in my daily life. (Any Book Recommendation?)

Comment: @JessePFrancis What about Limits?

Comment: @user1444692 , you wouldn't realize but limits are derivative are almost used in controlling every phenomenon you see, like even your PC or anything you are using, At some point in it's creation it must have required those equation involving limits or derivative and since derivative in general is a form of limit from first principles , you have it there as well

Comment: I completely agree with Mann, if you look at the definition of the derivative for any real life function, it will be evident what the application of it is.

Comment: to use limits in your everyday life, try walking half of the way to school, then half of the distance remaining after that, then half of the way you still have to go, then....

Comment: Velocity is computed by a limit (it the derivative of the position), as well as acceleration (which is the derivative of velocity).

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't view limits as a tool to solve problems. Instead, you should view limits as a way to describe situations (or ask more interesting problems).

The derivative is a perfect example of this. If you want to express the idea of "instantaneous rate of change," you are going to use limits to do this.

For another example, suppose you have a biased coin and you want to know how often you will get heads when you flip this coin. You know that if you flip the coin many times you will be able to approximate the probability of heads with some degree of confidence. Furthermore, you know that the larger the number of times you flip, the more confident you can be and you know that if you flip enough times you can be as confident as you want.

This is a scenario that would make a lot of sense to describe using limits.

Comment: I think you mean biased coin?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You might have calculated $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ during your course work ($=0$)- what does it mean? Does it mean $\frac{1}{n}=0$ for some n?

In other words, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ is a neat and accurate way of saying, as the value of n gets bigger, $\frac{1}{n}$ is almost near 0 (and never equals 0).

---

Have you heard of [Zeno's Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox)? Mathematically, we will say, he will never reach the target (which is the real solution). But in reality, doesn't it sound a bit absurd? He reaches almost there, but not exactly there - do you think it has something to do with limits as I explained above?

---

Also, it may be hard to find a direct application of a mathematical concept. But it may be a tool used in one of the concepts which has direct application in real life. Limit for example, is one such. Derivatives are widely used. You might have already studied that [derivatives are defined using limits](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfDerivative.aspx) in analysis. You might have learned integration, but have you ever wondered [how integration is defined](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnofDefiniteIntegral.aspx)?

Once you get into higher classes, for nearly every other thing, limits are going to haunt you!

Answer (score 2):

A great way to see applications of the derivative is to consider real life functions, and look at the units you get when you apply Newton's Quotient.

As an example, lets say you have a velocity function based on time, then if you apply Newton's Quotient, you will see you are left with $m/s^2$(acceleration), while a position function will yield a velocity in $m/s$

As for books, I suppose it depends on where your interests lie.

Answer (score 1):

Derivatives have some applications in economics, for example marginal cost, and I believe that marginal cost is used a lot in business applications.